# Let user Send Tweet (native App) by hitting web URL

Tags: url, mobile, android-intent, twitter

I would need some help here. We are having a Mobile webpage, and would like to use the users Native TWITTER APP (iOS/Android) to let him share something on Twitter.

So we set up this code:

```
<a href="twitter://tweet?text=I share this on Twitter from a website">Share this on Twitter</a>
```

the Mobile Device is showing us this message when hitting the link on mobile webpage: Cannot load the Tweet, try again later.

Does anybody know the right url to use the native App to send a pre-configured Tweet?